# I created a Meteor To Do list and have been using it for months. Now it is completely blank.

Tags: meteor

My todo list was working great and have been using it for work.  However recently it just up and everything in the list got deleted.  Is there anyway to recover it?

Comment: Did you do a meteor reset? If not, can you give us more of a clue as to what happened?

Comment: Assuming you still have access to mongodb, what's in there?